# How to Disable A Wordpress Function when viewing the site in Mobile Version?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, gallery, jquery-isotope

I have a Custom Gallery Shortcode because I am using the isotope in my gallery page. So basically, I have one page for gallery and I just drag and drop all my images here and have the isotope layout by dessandro do the rest. In addition, I am using Fancybox as my lightbox for a full version of the image when clicked. These are all in the functions.php custom gallery I created.

It's looking good, however, in mobile, I want to disable this feature, the fancybox, since it's a bit awkward having a lightbox in such a small device.

My solution would be, disable the Custom Gallery Function I created in my functions.php so that the native gallery of wordpress (which is cool btw in the new update 3.5) will take effect and therefore disable the isotope as well with the fancybox.

If the user clicks on the images on mobile version, it will then link to the attachment.php template instead of the fancybox since the custom function is now disabled.

A great example would be
http://thereason.us/

This site is in wordpress so that I know its possible. Anyone has an idea?

My Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what they're doing is that they are checking if the screen width is over `500` pixels and if it is, then they open the lightbox, otherwise they keep the default action of the link and it opens the attachment page.

So, I'd suggest that you change your function to add a `data-attachment` or a different attribute to the anchors that link to your images that will hold the URL to the attachment page.

Then in your JS, first bind a click event to your lightboxed links, for instance:

```
(function($){
    $(".gallery a[href$='.jpg'], .gallery a[href$='.png'], .gallery a[href$='.jpeg'], .gallery a[href$='.gif']").on('click', function(){
        if ( parseInt($(window).width()) < 500 ) {
            window.location.href = $(this).attr('data-attachment');
            return false;
        }
    });
    // Initialize Fancybox
    $(".gallery a[href$='.jpg'], .gallery a[href$='.png'], .gallery a[href$='.jpeg'], .gallery a[href$='.gif']").attr('rel','gallery').attr('class','fancybox').fancybox();
})(jQuery);
```

Then instantiate the lightbox. This should in theory bind your previous function prior to the lightbox one, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Hi Nikola, Thanks so much for the reply. So this is actually a javascript thing ha. Im not really so familiar with js so can you please see my code over here: 


`<script>(function($) {

 $(".gallery a[href$='.jpg'], .gallery a[href$='.png'], .gallery a[href$='.jpeg'], .gallery a[href$='.gif']").attr('rel','gallery').attr('class','fancybox').fancybox(); 

})(jQuery);`</script>

Comment: So, this is the code that initializes fancybox. See my updated answer for more specific code.

Comment: Thanks Nikola. It still doesn't work but I think I'm close. Thanks for the code that you gave. It's a start.

Comment: I hope you'll be able to figure it out :) don't forget to post your answer and accept it once you get it all working :)